# Select list does not show the value which is bound to

Tags: angularjs

Here is the view:

```
  <select ng-model="c_id" ng-selected="c_id" name="cov" id="cov">
    <option ng-repeat="cover in Options" value="{{ cover.id }}">
      {{ cover.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
```

where `c_id` and `Options` are $scope properties. When I choose an option, its value(cover.id) applies to `c_id` which is saved to the database. However, when I reload the page, even if `c_id` has a value the corresponding `cover.name` does not appear as selected in my drop down list. What do I have to add/change?

Comment: Is `cover.id` a number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `ng-options`:

```
<select ng-model="c_id" ng-options="cover.name as cover.id for cover in Options"></select>
```

Here is a [**demo on CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLyJNN?editors=1010#0) based on simple data.

Comment: Actually, it is the other way round what I want: `cover.id as cover.name`